# JTable doesn't show up in UI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, awt

I want to create a sample table on a UI. But it doesn't show up whatever I tried. Maybe someone can help me?

```
public void createGUI(){
        JFrame myframe = new JFrame("Frame");
        JButton firstButton = new JButton("Connect");


        myframe.setLayout(null);
        myframe.setVisible(true);
        myframe.setSize(500, 500);
        //myframe.add(firstButton);


        firstButton.addActionListener(new handler("ConnectButton"));
        firstButton.setSize(150, 100);
        firstButton.setLocation(100, 100);

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                "Last Name",
                "Sport",
                "# of Years",
                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith",
                 "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "Doe",
                 "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Sue", "Black",
                 "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Jane", "White",
                 "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Joe", "Brown",
                 "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
            };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setVisible(true);

        //JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        //scrollPane.setVisible(true);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        myframe.add(table);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you set layout to `null` in this line:

`myframe.setLayout(null);`

Just remove this line and it will work nicely. Because window can't be shown with layout set to null. So once you remove this line the default layout will be used.

Here is some more information about layout managers you might want to read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

The second thing i removed was this line:

```
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

You should use `myframe.pack();` instead so it packs all components on your frame.

So I ended up whit that:

```
public static void createGUI() {
        JFrame myframe = new JFrame("Frame");
        JButton firstButton = new JButton("Connect");

        myframe.setSize(500, 500);

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
            "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
                "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
                "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
                "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
                "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setVisible(true);

        myframe.add(table);
        myframe.pack();           // added this
        myframe.setVisible(true); // and moved this from top
    }
```

So the end result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This line `myframe.setVisible(true);` should also be **last,** just after `pack()` ..

Comment: Didn't work out Kiki :/  the problem is not that the window won't show up, it's just the table. I set the layout to "null" so that I can place the elements where I want, that was the plan. But I will inform me more about layoutmanager :) btw. is the code you posted working in your program? It didn't in mine for some reason :(

Comment: @Dyrdek i updated the code and the frame with table shows up nicely.

Comment: Ok thanks Kiki ;) I will try it and look for an error in my project.

Comment: I created a new project with your exact code Kiki. And it work (not suprising) :) So I have to figure out what is wrong with my original project.

Comment: @Kiki Thanks a lot.. Its been about a week i was struggling with this. Your answer saved ma LIFE !!!! :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a layout manager [myframe.setLayout(null)], so you have to deal with location and size by yourself.

Try to add:

```
  table.setLocation(1, 1);
  table.setSize(200,200);
```

and it will work.